# How can I make my DisplayLinked monitor display WPF apps correctly?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I am running Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro connected to a Kensington Universal Multi-Display adapter. When I have a WPF application on the monitor it doesn't display correctly. WPF applications will not repaint themselves except for the title bar. When I drag the app over there and release the drag the application looks fine, but I can't interact with it because it won't repaint itself. If I make another window come on top of it, I have to drag the WPF application to a different monitor to get it to repaint.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried updating your [DisplayLink driver](http://www.displaylink.com/support/downloads.php) (from Displaylink.com) to the latest?

Comment: This is a driver issue.  I believe techie007's answer should solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just updated to the latest driver and it did not fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to Windows Aero mode.  This has been discussed on the DisplayLink forum as a known issue when not using Aero.

To turn Aero on:

1. Right Click on the Desktop
2. Click Personalize
3. Select an Aero Theme.